# Moving channel from one msm site to another

Tags: multi-site-manager, channel

Is there a way to move a channel from one msm site to another?  Both sites are within the site  installation.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
As I quickly look through the database it seems that the site_id column is used all over the place, including within the entries, so there is a high chance this isn't going to work without a great deal of messing around.

If you're not confident fiddling with the database directly then it's probably best not to even try this.

There is no way to do this from the Controlpanel but you *might* be able to do it by making a change directly in the database.

**THIS IS NOT TESTED - BACKUP YOUR DATABASE FIRST AND WORK ON A DEV VERSION OF THE SITE**

Once you're backed up. Look in the database and get the id of the site you wish to change TO from the exp_sites table.

Then go to exp_channels, find the channel you wish to move and update it's site_id value for the new channel. Don't change anything else.

You will also need to change the site_id value for the field group associated with the channel.

If you're using categories on that channel then you will need to change the site_id of the category group too. Just ensure that no other channels are using the same category group.

I think that's it but as I said **back up your database - I make no guarantees!**

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this on my local dev, but for now I'll just recreate channel and categories.